# Problem with Apache James

Tags: java, james

I'm trying send email using Apache James, as server,  for external account and I'm receiving the following exception :

```
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Requested action not taken: relaying denied

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1686)
... 6 more
```

Somebody please help me to resolve the issue

Thanks in advance

Alisson

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you didn't authenticate to the SMTP server. Show some code if you need more help.

Comment: I'm using apache commons email framework for send out email.

Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("NAME_SERVER.com.br");
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("red", "red"));
email.setFrom("red@NAME_SERVER.com.br");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
email.addTo("USER_EMAIL@gmail.com");
email.setDebug(true);
email.send();

thanks!

Comment: @Alisson Could you add this code to the question and format it? It would be easier to read that way.

Comment: I'm using apache commons email framework for send out email.   `Email email = new SimpleEmail(); email.setHostName("NAME_SERVER.com.br");  email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("red", "red")); email.setFrom("red@NAME_SERVER.com.br"); email.setSubject("TestMail");                      email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)"); email.addTo("USER_EMAIL@gmail.com");           email.setDebug(true);                                    email.send(); `                                                   thanks!

Comment: Now, I send email, in the log it tell that was sent, but it don't arrive in the gmail.

Answer (score 1):

You can not send an email to external mail addresses, say for instance your gmail id, unless and until you have a static IP. The SMTP of the server has the configuration to stop emails from dynamic IPs.

Comment: Are IPs considered dynamic because of some registry somewhere? Where can I see what is considered dynamic?